# Passing LoginContext as Credentials for Repository Login in JCR (java content Repository)

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

I have been passing logincontext object in as credentials to get session for repository login like this

```
Repository repo = new Jcr(new Oak()).createRepository();
    final LoginContext lc= JaasAuthenticationTest.getlogincontext(); 
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
        public LoginContext getLoginContext() { return lc; }
        };
Session session = repo.login(credentials);
```

and JaasAuthenticationTest Looks like

```
    lc = new LoginContext("nikhil", new TestCallbackHandler(name, password));
    return lc;
```

But shows error:

```
javax.jcr.LoginException: Login Failure: all modules ignored
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.repository.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:262)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.repository.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:220)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray()));
```